# What does it mean by "depends non-linearly upon the highest order derivatives" mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

PDE is classified as linear and non-linear ones.
Non-linear PDE is further classified as semi-linear, quasi-linear, and fully non-linear. In Evan's book, fully non-linear PDE is PDE that "depends non-linearly upon the highest order derivatives." What does it exactly mean? If I have, say, $x^2f_{xx}=0$ then since $x^2$ is non-linear, is it fully nonlinear? What if we have two highest order derivative terms, for example, $x^2f_{xx}+y^2 f_{xy}=1$?

Comment: I understand this rather as for example : $(f_{xx})^2+2f=0$

Comment: The examples given in the question count as linear, because the second-order partial derivatives of $f$ aren't getting squared or anything. It could help to look at the definition of a linear differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In differential equations, a non-linear DE means that the unknown function, not the independent variables, is nonlinear. So your second example,
\begin{align}
x^2f_{xx}+y^2f_{xy}=1,
\end{align}
is linear as the unknown function $f(x,y)$ has no non-linear terms.

So a fully non-linear PDE would be something like
\begin{align}
x^2(f_{xx})^2+y^2f_{xy}=1.
\end{align}
Here's a list of non-linear PDEs from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nonlinear_partial_differential_equations

Comment: I wouldn't use the phrasing that for a differential equation to be nonlinear means "the unknown function is nonlinear", because for example the ODE $y' = y, y(0) = 1$ is linear but the unknown function is nonlinear.